# Should "crossed" really be there as an equivalent of this definition?

Tags: word-usage

I read a definition of the word "squint" in [Merriam Webster Dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squint) which was:

> of the eyes : not having the visual axes parallel : CROSSED

"Crossed" (or cross-eyed) is in fact a **type** of a pathological condition relating to eye known as Strabismus or squint-eyed. So I don't think it should really be there as the equivalent of the definition because it is a **type** of the squint-eyed disease which is broader term and the type is specific.

Comment: That's not how it works. The definition of *squint* is correct; *crossed* is "a cross-reference immediately following a boldface colon," which "is a synonymous cross-reference. It may stand alone as the only definitional matter for an entry or for **a sense or subsense of an entry.**" (My emphasis) It's something else to look at which may be helpful. However, criticising dictionaries isn't really a part of our purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Strabismus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strabismus) is the medical term for a permanent misalignment.  Strabismus is derived from the Greek for squint.

But, looking down your nose causes the eyes to misalign temporarily. This is also referred to as cross-eyed, or having your eyes *crossed*.

[Squinting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squint) is layman's term and hence encompasses more than one phenomenon: Closing one's eyes to get a better view, looking askance, etc.

Just for completeness, [*saccades*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccade) are movements of the eye horizontally between fixed points.  [*Nystagmus*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nystagmus) is a twitching type of involuntary saccade usually due to neurological or extra-occular muscle issues.